# how to print output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, output, division

I tried replacing listBox1.Items.Add with Console.WriteLine. I tried replacing listBox1.Items.Add with Console.WriteLine. I tried replacing listBox1.Items.Add with Console.WriteLine. I tried replacing listBox1.Items.Add with Console.WriteLine. I tried replacing listBox1.Items.Add with Console.WriteLine.

How can I print the output?

```
    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        int[] bluesky = new int[100];

        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0 & i % 7 == 0)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("BlueSky");
            }
            else if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("Blue");
            }
            else if (i % 7 == 0)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("Sky");
            }
            else listBox1.Items.Add(i = i + 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? What do you want to print to?

Comment: Did you want a Console application instead of a WinForms application?

Comment: Yes, a console application would work @RufusL

Comment: Then create a console application instead of a winforms application, and use `Console.WriteLine()`...

Comment: Got it, thanks. @RufusL

Answer (score 1):

From the comments (and the question), it sounds like a console application will work for this. After you create the application, you can use `Console.WriteLine()` to output values to the user. At the end of the method, you may want to add a `Console.ReadKey()` so that the output doesn't disappear before the user has a chance to read it.

For example (just note the last two lines that wait for user input):

```
static void Main()
{
    Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
        .Select(num => 
            num % 3 == 0 
                ? num % 7 == 0 ? "BlueSky": "Blue" 
                : num % 7 == 0 ? "Sky" : num.ToString())
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

FYI, the code above makes heavy use of the [ternary operator :?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), but is really just a condensed version of the following:

```
foreach(var number in Enumerable.Range(1, 100))
{
    if (number % 3 == 0)
    {
        if (number % 7 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BlueSky");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Blue");
        }
    }
    else if(number % 7 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sky");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Rich Textbox ?

```
int[] bluesky = new int [100];
        for (int i = 0; i < bluesky.Length; i ++)
        {
        if( i % 3 == 0 && i % 7 == 0){
            richtextbox1.AppendText("Blue Sky");
        }
        //not going to do the rest this is just an example
```

}

You can "print" to anything that can contain text such as listboxes, rich textbox, textbox, label just to name a few.

The question doesn't spesify to what you must print though...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a console application to do this (Edit: To print to the console that is, theres lots.of.other things you can print to in win forms or wpf like text boxes or labels etc). There is a template for this in visual studio. To write to the console you use the static Console.WriteLine method
 It takes a string or any object and calls ToString behind the scenes.

Ie

```
//Outputs 'Hello, World!'
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

//Outputs '1'
Console.WriteLine(1);
```

It can also be used with format strings(I won't explain those here)

There is plenty out there for you to read about with a very quick Google search